# C++ : No matching function for call to std::deque<SnakePart>::emplace_front

Tags: c++, c++11, deque

Recently I have been working on remaking my remake of the classic snake game, this time employing a deque instead of a linked list for the snake's tail. I construct a tail segment and try to emplace it at the front of the deque and get a strange error.

`no matching function for call to 'std::deque<SnakePart>::emplace_front(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'|`

Since I am still quite new to C++ I am clueless as to why this error is occurring. It would be appreciated if someone could help me solve this conundrum.

`SnakePart.cpp`

http://pastebin.com/verR9bpn

`Snake.h`
http://pastebin.com/XUyNAVKK

## Minimal Complete & Verifiable Example:

```
#include <deque>

struct Test {
    Test(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y){}
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main () {
    int x = 4, y = 5;

    std::deque<Test> tester;
    tester.emplace_front({x, y});
    return 0;
}
```

## SnakePart.cpp

```
#include "Snake.h"
#include <deque>

void SnakePart::advance(int x, int y, bool loose_tail = true) {
        parts.emplace_front({x, y});

        if(loose_tail)
            parts.pop_back();
}
```

## Snake.h

```
#ifndef SNAKE_H_INCLUDED
#define SNAKE_H_INCLUDED

#include <deque>

class SnakeHead {
private:
    int posX, posY;

    // Snake head functions
    void input();
    void movement();
};

class SnakePart {
private:
    std::deque<SnakePart> parts;

    void advance(int x, int y, bool loose_tail);
};

#endif // SNAKE_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Don't post links to the source, copy-paste the source straight into the question body. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (and also please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I shall add the code to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`emplace_front`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/emplace_front) function takes its arguments and passes to a suitable constructor in the contained object. The `Test` class doesn't have a constructor which takes a single [initializer-list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) argument. It have a constructor taking two `int` arguments which means you could use

```
tester.emplace_front(x, y);
```

It also have a copy-constructor which means you could do

```
tester.emplace_front(Test{x, y});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 1):

Remove curly braces from `emplace_front` function params. Semantic of `emplace*` functions means that arguments passed as like in constructor of container type `T`. Passing it with `{}` makes argument type is `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Doing so causes an error in the C++ standard library's `new_allocator.h` file